# how do i rotate a paragraph in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to rotate this div 90 degrees but it doesn't seem to be working. There is no bootstrap class to do it and css isn't doing anything to it

```css
#socials {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <svg class="svgOne position-absolute bottom-0 start-1" width="13" height="334" viewBox="0 0 13 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="13" height="334" fill="black"/>
    </svg>
    <svg class="svgTwo position-absolute top-2 start-1" width="13" height="176" viewBox="0 0 13 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="13" height="176" fill="black"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="fs-4 text-light" id="socials">Socials</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is an image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Nf6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me, but your transform origin seems off if you want the text inside the black svg areas.  I changed the html/body color just so you can see it better.

```css
#socials {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
html, body { background-color: #333; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <svg class="svgOne position-absolute bottom-0 start-1" width="13" height="334" viewBox="0 0 13 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="13" height="334" fill="black"/>
    </svg>
    <svg class="svgTwo position-absolute top-2 start-1" width="13" height="176" viewBox="0 0 13 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="13" height="176" fill="black"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="fs-4 text-light" id="socials">Socials</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I added exactly what you did and nothing happened

Comment: @memento Then you need to post a reproducible problem, because based on what you told us and what you posted, we can't help since it works just fine for us.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#socials {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="socials">
    <svg class="svgOne position-absolute bottom-0 start-1" width="13" height="334" viewBox="0 0 13 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="13" height="334" fill="black"/>
    </svg>
 <div class="fs-4 text-light" >Socials</div>
    <svg class="svgTwo position-absolute top-2 start-1" width="13" height="176" viewBox="0 0 13 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="13" height="176" fill="black"/>
    </svg>
   
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I just change this to negative: -90deg

Comment: sorry but this did nothing :(